# Changing word printed depending on selected value from dropdown

Tags: php, html, forms, select

```
<form id="category" method="post">
            <?php
            $option = null;
            ?>
            <label for="query1"> Please choose a category: </label>
            <select name="query1" onchange= <?php $option == $_POST['query1']; echo "<p> poop </p>" ?>>
                <option value="Youtubers"> Youtubers </option>
                <option value="Channels"> Channels </option>
            </select>
            </br>
            <label for="query2"> Please choose a sort method for <?php if(isset($_POST['query1'])){
            if($option == "Youtubers"){
                echo "<p> Youtubers </p>";
            }
            if($option == "Channels"){
                echo "<p> Channels </p>";
            }
        }?>: </label>
                <select id="query2">
                    <option value="Sub Count"> Sub Count </option>
                    <option value="Origin"> Origin </option>
                    <option value=""> Origin </option>
                </select>
            </form>
```

I am trying to change the last word of my second query to be whatever option is selected from the first query. I am storing the input in $option but it seems to not be working.

Comment: PHP is a server side language. You need a client side language (e.g. JavaScript) if you want to process user inputs before posting the form to the server.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the function for your [`onChange`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp) attribute in your select tag.